# Crystal Report for VS2008 error: "The request could not be submitted for background processing"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm developing with VS2008 and Crystal Report for VS2008.

There is a report that includes an image object, which shows a JPG file stored as a blob field in Oracle database.

Most of the times that report exports to PDF correctly, but some times returns error:"The request could not be submitted for background processing" and crashes completely CR.

I realized that it crashes depending on the JPG file that has to show, but I can't determine what feature of the JPG file is making it to crash.

I have already installed this Service Pack but no change at all:

Crystal Reports Basic for VS 2008 - Service Pack 1

Extract of my code:

```
Try    
           Dim oRpt As New cr_my_report    
           oRpt.SetDataSource(dt)   ' dt is a datatable filled from an Oracle database query    
            Dim exportOpts As ExportOptions = oRpt.ExportOptions    
            oRpt.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat

            oRpt.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile

            oRpt.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = New DiskFileDestinationOptions

            CType(oRpt.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions, DiskFileDestinationOptions).DiskFileName = Server.MapPath("../Temp/" + PDFName)


            oRpt.Export()  ' here it crashes

        Catch ex As Exception


        Finally    
            oRpt.Close()    
            oRpt.Dispose()    
        End Try
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intermittent Crystal Reports error "The request could not be submitted for background processing."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181255/intermittent-crystal-reports-error-the-request-could-not-be-submitted-for-backg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many days, finally I discovered what is the root of problem. The thing is that CR for VS2008 or later versions, **can’t handle jpg files in CMYK mode**. CR only can handle jpg files in RGB mode.

It’s funny that lower versions of CR (the one that came with VS2003) could handle any kind of jpg files. Thanks, Crystal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same issue on Oracle as it is for SQL Server.  Apparently the issue was fixed in sp4.

ADAPT01407087
Description:
When using an SQL server native ODBC connection, the Field Explorer displays the Blob datatype as “String” instead of “Picture”.
The cause of the problem is that any field that uses the data types varchar(max), nvarchar(max), and varbinary(max) in the SQL
Server 2005 driver may fail to be correctly mapped.
New Behavior:
This problem is resolved

If you can you should update to the latest service pack.  You can find all of them for 2008 at http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27917

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The solution was to set my default printer to another printer. I ran the report and it all worked correctly. I then re-set the printer back to the original one and the report still worked.